# Is it possible to call an already declared method dynamically from within a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, dynamic, this

So I have a class with some private methods with the same prefix. And I wanted to do a public
method that can call them using the prefix and a suffix with an idea like this :

```
class MyClass {
   #privateMethod1(){
      console.log("Hello");
   }
   #privateMethod2(){
      console.log("world");
   }
   #privateMethod3(){
      console.log("!");
   }
   publicMethod(...names){
      names.forEach((name) => {
         this.["#privateMethod"+`${name}`]();
      });
   }
}
let test = new MyClass();
test.publicMethod(1,2,3); // Should display "Hello world!"
```

But is it even possible? I tried to use objects but nothing seems to work

Comment: it's `this[ ]` not `this.[ ]`

Comment: Also private methods and fields cannot be accessed dynamically anyway.

Comment: Ah I didn't know you could not access private methods dynamically. Well now I know. Thanks!

Comment: Though you can probably define a private property as an object, define the methods as it's members, and then access *them* dynamically.